# How to extract line numbers from a multi-line string in Vim?

Tags: regex, string, vim

In my opinion, Vimscript does not have a lot of features for manipulating strings.
I often use `matchstr()`, `substitute()`, and less often `strpart()`.
Perhaps there is more than that.

For example, what is the best way to remove all text between line numbers in the following string `a`?

```vim
let a = "\%8l............\|\%11l..........\|\%17l.........\|\%20l...."  " etc.
```

I want to keep only the digits and put them in a list:

```vim
['8', '11', '17', '20']  " etc.
```

(Note that the text between line numbers can be different.)

Comment: Please give a sample of what you want to obtain.

Comment: `'<,'>s/(\d+).*$/\1/g` or describe what you need more precisely

Comment: romainl, kirilloid, please see after edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for split()

```
echo split(a, '[^0-9]\+')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Given the new constraint: *only the numbers from `\%d\+l`*, I'd do:

```
echo map(split(a, '|'), "matchstr(v:val, '^%\\zs\\d\\+\\zel')")
```

NB: your vim variable is incorrectly formatted, to use only one backslash, you'd need to write your string with single-quotes. With double-quotes, here you'd need two backslashes.
So, with

```
let b = '\%8l............\|\%11l..........\|\%17l.........\|\%20l....'
```

it becomes

```
echo map(split(b, '\\|'), "matchstr(v:val, '^\\\\%\\zs\\d\\+\\zel')")
```

Comment: This is nice Luc but it doesn't exactly what I want. It split up also if there is a digit in the text between %\d\+l's

Comment: Luc, What would be the split code if there is also `>-<` in string "b": `\%8l.....\|\%>10l-\%<15l\.....\|\%17l.....`?   The result must be `['8','11-14','17'] Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sorry, the result must be `['8', '11', '12', '13', '14', '17']`

Answer (score 2):

One can take advantage of the substitute with an expression feature (see
`:help sub-replace-\=`) to run over all of the target matches, appending them
to a list.

```
:let l=[] | call substitute(a, '\\%\(\d\+\)l', '\=add(l,submatch(1))[1:0]', 'g')
```

Comment: Damn. We can always learn new vim tricks. I wasn't aware that `substitute()` supports `\=`. Thanks!

Comment: Ib, do you know what would be your split code if there is also `>-<` in string "b": `\%8l.....\|\%>10l-\%<15l.....\|\%17l...`. ? The result must be `['8', '11-14', '17']` or even better `['8', '11', '12', '13', '14', '17']`

Comment: I have created a function to fill block of lines with spaces and another to copy block of lines to clipboard. I select them first in another function. :)

Comment: @Remonn:  It is enough to use `\%>10l\%<15l` to match a range of lines (number 9 through 14). For what purpose do you insert a hyphen between those atoms?

Comment: "@Ib, I found the solution trying, trying and trying :) Using your above regex with this regex does the job to put the "-" in the list as well `:call substitute(s:zoek, '\\%[<>]*\(\d\+\)l\.*\\%[<>]*\(\d\+\)l\.*', '\=add(l,(submatch(1)+1)."-".(submatch(2)-1))[1:0]', 'g')`  :)  --- Why I need the hyphen? I want to keep the ">" and "<" together in only one index.